# can not initialize a two dimensional array in java using for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I can not initialize a two dimensional array using for loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Quater{
      public static void main(String[] args){
        //declare an array
        double product[][]=new double[3][2];

        //declare a Scanner object
        Scanner userInput=new Scanner(System.in);

        //ask the user for input

        System.out.println("Please enter your data");
        for(int i=0;i<=1;i++)
        {
          for(int j=0;j<=2;j++){
          System.out.println(" enter your data");

          product[i][j]=userInput.nextDouble();
        } 
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem is when I try to enter the third number, This shut down and not working, however, if I make it new double[100][100], this can work and allow me to enter 6 number.

Comment: What about it is "not working"?  Be specific.  If you have a stack trace, include that, too.

Comment: Stack Traces.... We need Stack Traces...

Comment: You should initialize every array in your array of arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The outer cycle iterates over rows and inner over columns, therefore you need to have an array of dimensions `double[2][3]`, not `double[3][2]` that you use.

Answer (score 1):

If you make your array `new double[3][2]`, then you can access `product[i][j]` where `i` goes up to 3-1=2, and `j` goes up to 2-1=1.  That is, the bounds of the indexes in the same order in which they appear in the `new`.  But you're trying to access `product[i][j]` where `j` is 2.

Answer (score 1):

Corrected code. Look on this. Condition of two fors was fixed. You should do it using length and better is using '<' not '<='. That prevent you from many `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` .

```
public static void main(String[] args){
            //declare an array
            double product[][]=new double[3][2];

            //declare a Scanner object
            Scanner userInput=new Scanner(System.in);

            //ask the user for input

            System.out.println("Please enter your data");
            for(int i=0;i<product.length;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<product[i].length;j++){
                    System.out.println(" enter your data");

                    product[i][j]=userInput.nextDouble();

                }
            }
        }
```

to see the efect you can simply paste down that code.

```
for (double[] doubles : product) {
                for (double aDouble : doubles) {
                    System.out.println(aDouble);
                }
            }
```

Comment: More than corrected code, you should explain what was wrong, how to fix it and why this fix works.

Comment: *`OutOfArrayExceptions`* you mean `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Yes `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` :)